# What is the best practice for cleaning eggs when some in the carton have broken?

Tags: eggs, storage

Carrying eggs home after purchase some of your eggs break and spill onto the rest. You take them all out carefully but don’t want to store them with exposed white/yolk on the shells lest they get very rotten and smelly.

But washing all of them as I did last week risks removing the bloom and thus shortening the storage life.

What is the best practice here to maximise shelf life?

Note: these are unwashed eggs in England.

Comment: We still don't know where you live or if your country's eggs are already washed.

Comment: Fair point; They aren’t prewashed, and I’m in England.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For UK unwashed eggs, I'd just wipe them off with some kitchen roll, allow them to dry & put them in the fridge, as normal.

You can't 'fix' it by washing them thoroughly, as then they become 'amateur washed eggs' with less protection than they would have in a country that does wash eggs as a matter of course.
A bit of dried egg really won't be a prime target for going off, compared to a badly-washed one.

Comment: Great point. But what do you think I should do now that I’ve washed all of them to be rather squeaky-clean?

Comment: Eat them inside a week.